# How do I apply a renormalization technique to estimate the fractal dimension of a diffusion limited aggregate?

Tags: renormalization, diffusion, fractals

Diffusion Limited Aggregation (DLA) is an interesting phenomena observed in nature and discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-limited_aggregation). From a theoretical view point, it'd be nice to know about the fractal dimension of a DLA formed on a 2d square lattice.

My thinking is that as follows: The DLA is self-similar, so renormalization techniques might be used to estimate the fractal dimension. The problem is that I don't really know how to go about picking a suitable renormalization.

I tried simplifying the model as follows. Instead of computing the DLA in full, I only computed particle attachments to a square that is the effective 'diameter' of the current DLA. When enough particles attach to expand the diameter beyond just the surface of this renormalization square, I renormalize the DLA to another square with an expanded diameter. By summing the average number of particles needed to expand the renormalization square for each square length, the total number particles in the DLA is approximated. The scale is the length of a side of the renormalized square. However using this method, I get an estimate of 2 for the fractal dimension.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I know that the book "Fractal Geometry: Mathematical Foundations and Applications" by Kenneth Falconer has a good section on DLA. I believe he uses the box-counting method, though I don't remember whether the dimension is found analytically, or just computed.

Comment: @David I'll look into that. I was hoping to get a theoretical prediction that matches up with experiment. The error on my prediction is around 15%.

Comment: @Zach466920 Renormalising DLA seems very hard to me. The Renormalisation Group was successfully applied to the related (and simpler) problems of [directed percolation](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0511456) and [interface growth](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4650). Take a look at the references.

Answer (score 2):

For the select few who'd care for an answer to this question. There's actually a rich theory for the solution.

I personally took an interest in the subject and eventually wrote a paper on the subject. I even gave a presentation [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dd3n73kgX9U). Let me know if you want a paper.

There are also other people who've worked on the less general problem. The solution techniques involve both [Kinetic Renormalization](http://mr.chem.unc.edu/reprints/articles/1989_2.pdf) and [Fixed Scale Transformation techniques](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037843719190267G#heading_0).

So, I thank the community for NOT answering the question. It provided me with a great research opportunity :)